# Docker suddenly stopped working with Wireguard, unable to fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz during build

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, docker, wireguard

Wireguard and Docker have been working for quite a while together under this same configuration, but this morning I started working and I couldn't get my docker containers to talk to AWS properly.

I have a feeling this is some kind of network change at the co-working space I'm at that's conflicting with my machine's configuration. The only way I've been able to confirm that is if I turn WG off, docker build + running the containers starts working again, or if I keep WG on but connect to my phone's hotspot, it also works.

Furthermore, I couldn't build containers via docker-compose. The simplest way I've been able to replicate the problem is via:

```
jacob@jacob-ThinkPad-P52s:~$ docker run --rm -ti alpine apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
```

Running that container with apk update just ends in an endless hang trying to get APKINDEX.tar.gz. If I navigate to the same URL on the host OS, I don't have any issues.

I have a similar issue trying to contact the AWS SES service from within the docker containers, this just hangs forever:

```
jacob@jacob-ThinkPad-P52s:~$ docker run --rm -ti alpine wget https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Connecting to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (54.157.160.123:443)
```

Doing the same from the host machine gives a response immediately. The container is running on a non-default 10.254.0.0/16 subnet (has an IP of 10.254.0.1).

The co-working space is using the 10.0.0.0/16 subnet:

```
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:3b:8f:32:92:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.24/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
       valid_lft 80541sec preferred_lft 80541sec
    inet6 fe80::c263:54cf:5e8c:a865/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Wireguard configuration:

```
jacob@jacob-ThinkPad-P52s:~$ sudo wg showconf wg0
[Interface]
ListenPort = 51222
FwMark = 0xca6c
PrivateKey = <private key>
DNS = 172.31.0.2

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <server ip>:41194
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

Some other potentially useful info:

```
jacob@jacob-ThinkPad-P52s:~$ ip route
default via 10.1.0.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.1.0.0/16 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.24 metric 600 
10.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.254.0.5 
10.255.100.0/24 dev br-b06c6d86e92b proto kernel scope link src 10.255.100.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp4s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.30.0.0/21 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.2

jacob@jacob-ThinkPad-P52s:~$ uname -a
Linux jacob-ThinkPad-P52s 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

jacob@jacob-ThinkPad-P52s:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I'm honestly pretty past my abilities currently and am kind of firing in the dark here. Any help troubleshooting would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted docker since changing networking settings? A lot of the iptables entries are sensitive to the host interfaces remaining stable, and restarting dockerd (`systemctl restart docker`) will reset those.

Comment: @BMitch yep I have, I've done a full system restart too, nada. I'm currently looking at tcpdumpto see if packets are getting sent into the abyss or what.

Comment: Sounds a lot like routing from the container network namespace is going the wrong way since docker itself is resolving the hostnames for you. However I don't see any obvious routing conflicts. traceroute may help. nicolaka/netshoot is also my go to image for network debugging tools.

Comment: @BMitch it was the MTU value. The coworking space recently switched from Charter to AT&T and it looks like AT&T was dropping fragmented packets whereas Charter was somehow handling it? Anyways, setting docker to use a MTU of 1420 fixed the issue entirely!

Comment: Good find, I've dealt with that before (pre-docker) and it was never fun. Makes me wonder if something to do with the iptables rules, and maybe also wireguard, is blocking/dropping the packets that indicate the MTU needs to be reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coworking space recently switched from Charter to AT&T and something about the MTU being 1500 on Docker was too large I guess. Seems like AT&T drops fragmented packets which was resulting in infinite hangs. Setting the MTU to a lower value, 1420, instantly solved the issue.